# Can't send/receive text messages on Nexus 5

Tags: sms, nexus-5

My Nexus 5 has been able to send and receive text messages perfectly fine for 6 months now but as of a day or two ago it has just hasn't been able to send or receive messages from any text messaging app.

I am with Amaysim (in Australia), my phone is running Android 4.4.4 and I have tried sending messages from Hangouts, EvolveSMS and TextSecure and none have worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do any of the apps give error messages? Have you tried sending messages from a different SIM or a different phone? Do phone calls still work?

Comment: Haven't tried that. Yes, phone calls still work.

Comment: I should of made myself more clear, I can still make calls but I don't think I can receive them.

Comment: To narrow down the issue, as keepcalm suggested, try placing the SIM into a different phone and see whether it shows the same symptoms there. If so, it's not your Nex, and you rather need a replacement card (or other help from your provider). Also, try a different SIM in your Nex for the same reasons.

Comment: I can't do that for another 2 days (I'm camping and have to stay where I am). Would it help to mention that I still have mobile internet access?

Comment: It could be the network, have you contacted customer support and asked them about any issues? Have you tried re-setting up your APN and settings and so on?

Comment: I have tried contacting the support team but they weren't able to help. I found out today that Google was dropping text support in Hangouts as of the 2nd of July (yesterday for me) so perhaps that could have something to do with it? I haven't changed any settings at all so I'm not too sure what the problem is. I haven't tried re-setting up my APN settings yet.

Comment: Hangouts from WEB is not supporting SMS, nothing to do with the app on your phone. `Notably, the SMS feature from the Hangouts app for Android will still be available. Users can still send and receive text and multimedia messages in the Hangouts app.` from [this site here](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/internet/news/google-discontinues-sms-for-hangouts-might-integrate-google-voice-soon-551851) The network should be able to send your SMS settings to your device, and should be looking into this!

Comment: Sorry for the bump, I just want to say that I FINALLY got the problem fixed. Amaysim was not able to tell me what the problem was but they escalated it to Optus and had them sort it out. This can now be closed.

Comment: I face similar issue on nexus5, wish the solution had an answer.